# How to specify to grep that I want to select a path prefix when searching recursively?

Tags: grep

Example. I have a word that I am looking for, say **"cat"**. And I know that the word can be located anywhere under the current working directory. So I use **grep -r**, and this gives the results in the following form:

> ./example_root/[dir1|dir2]/[SOME_ARBITRARY_SUBPATH]/cat_file,

where

> cat_file

is the file that contains the word **"cat"**. What if I am only interested in

> /example_root/dir1/[whatever_path]

prefix for my path? How to I tell it to **grep**?

Comment: I don't think there's an option in grep to do so, may be apply `dirname` on the result? for example, `dirname /foo/baz/123.txt` gives `/foo/baz`

Comment: `grep -r 'cat' /example_root/dir1/[whatever_path]` ??

Comment: @Kusalananda, yep, this seems obvious now :), thanks

Comment: @Sundeep, thanks, I didn't know of dirname before

Comment: @Kusalananda, wait a second, the thing is that [whatever path] is long and I do not want to specify it, I want to be able to say "start looking from this prefix - /example_root/dir1, and then go wherever u like"

Comment: @АртемГеворгян Then delete that long bit. As far as I understand, you seem to be starting in the current directory even though you're interested in files under `./example_root/dir1`, so use that path as the starting point instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
grep -rl cat directory | xargs dirname
```

where

- `grep -rl cat directory`  search recursilvely (`-r`) for cat in directory and (`-l`) lisy files.
- `| xargs dirname` each file is "given" to `dirname`, which remove file part.

Answer (score 0):

@Kusalananda's answer in the comments is what I wanted: just do

```
grep -r 'cat' /example_root/dir1/
```

However, in case you want to retrieve directory names where the words reside, the following (credits to @Archemar) is handy.

```
grep -rl cat directory | xargs dirname
```